# Multiple MySQL rows with one form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that I would like to create up to 9 different MySQL rows with one process. The code I have as of right now doesn't throw any errors, but also does not insert any information into the database.

```
        $id    = '';
        $rid   = $_POST['rid'];
        $desc  = $_POST['desc'];
        $ename = $_POST['ename'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO event(id, rid, desc, ename) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("isss", $id, $rid, $desc, $ename);
            for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
                $rid   = $_POST['rid'   . $i];
                $desc  = $_POST['desc'  . $i];
                $ename = $_POST['ename' . $i];

                $stmt->execute();
            }
            include ("./html/schedule2.htm");
        } else {
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
```

I have edited the code to follow the comment instructions but still get an error that is very vague. Not sure what is going on...

Comment: You should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection. You can also insert multiple rows in on query separating the groups of values by commas: `VALUES (...),(...),(...)`. And add error handling.

Comment: What would be causing the code to not insert into the database tho? Prepared statements confuse me.

Comment: We'll never know until you add error handling :-) You could be sql-injecting yourself.

Comment: The reason it might be failing is because the POST content contains a single quote `'`, thus breaking your query.

Comment: You're not checking for errors so you won't see any. You're also open to SQL injection, your code could be shortened substantially by using array syntax names on your form, and you can insert multiple rows with a single `INSERT`. Where would you like us to start?

Comment: Have you checked if the results stores any error data?

Comment: @EdHamilton If they confuse you could could at least escape the strings for the POST data with: `$name1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['ename1']);`

Comment: Ok, I have changed everything around according to the answer below, but still getting an error that is vague. Not sure what the error in the query is as I am not familiar with these prepared statements. I'll be honest this is the first project I have worked on in almost ten years. I'm not familiar with much of anything that deals with php/mysql anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have pointed out that you should prepare/execute this. This is what it should look like.

```
$id    = '';
$rid   = $_POST['rid1'];
$desc  = $_POST['desc1'];
$ename = $_POST['ename1'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `event`(`id`, `rid`, `desc`, `ename`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $id, $rid, $desc, $ename);
$stmt->execute();

for ($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $rid   = $_POST['rid'   . $i];
    $desc  = $_POST['desc'  . $i];
    $ename = $_POST['ename' . $i];

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Also, I'd recommend using an array for your form elements. Like:

```
<input type="text" name="desc[]">
```

Comment: After I switched everything to the prepared statement i get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in public_html/ad1/index.php on line 315

Line 315:

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $id, $rid, $desc, $ename);

Comment: I have played around with the code for a bit and now the only thing i am seeing on the page is : "Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, ename) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1 "

Comment: @Edh `desc` is a reserved word in mysql that needs to be quoted in backticks.